# How to get the really executed stored procedure text

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, ado.net

My stored procedure return -1 if it is executed failed. I use ADO.NET to execute stored procedure. Now, I guess some parameter value is illegal, so the execution failed. But I don't know how to get the executed text, any idea?

Comment: Any code? Show us how you execute that SP.

Comment: Either debug the code and check what all parameters you are passing to Stored Proc or else run SQL sercer Profiler to check the exact text being passed and then run the same in SSMS.

Answer (score 1):

If you are preparing query as a type of NVARCHAR and then executing it, then you can use

> PRINT @Query

in SSMS to see the text of SP which it's going to execute.

Answer (score 0):

Execute following statement to get what exactly you executed:

```
SELECT object_name(b.objectid) AS obj_name, a.execution_count, a.last_execution_time, b.text
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats a
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(a.sql_handle) AS b
where text like '%Your_SP_NAME_HERE%'
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```